# how to insert an android webview programatically next to a textview?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, mobile-application

I need to insert my `Webview` right next to a `textview` with unique id, is there something like javascript's `Node.insertBefore();` in java.
I have tried the following: ex:

```
    LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.linear_view);
    webview = new WebView(this);
    webview.setId(10);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/");
    layout.addView(webview);
```

but in my case i can't get layout id, i will get the textview id only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```java
layout.addView(webView, layout.getChildCount())
```